# Coded UI - How do we find if something exists when IsVisible, Exists, TryGetClickablePoint etc all return true when I can't see the control?

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests

I am testing a WPF application and am not privy to it's exact workings but I am finding many instances where I need to find if a control is shown. All the traditional answers on this on Stack Overflow and MS forums etc say to use one of the following ...

IsVisible, 
Exists, 
TryGetClickablePoint, 
State (e.g. OffScreen

The problem is that for this system, many controls return true for all of those even when the control cannot be seen! They also return a point with co-ordinates (-1, -1, -1, -1) whether the control is visible or not.

The only thing I have had any success with is using a try catch finally. I try to click on the control and if that fails, I go in to the catch block. That takes 60 seconds to time out though and I am getting intermittent issues with tests that run 9 times out of 10. Maybe the constant use of try catch is causing performance issues.

Is there an approach that actually works when all the standard approaches fail? I have noticed lots of other people asking these question are also testing WPF. Is there something WPF developers are doing to hide controls that makes CodedUI think they are still present and visible etc. Are they just behind something?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a property `IsHitTestVisible` you can set on an UI element. It also depends on how the controls are hidden `Collapsed` or `Hidden`. Collapsed does not take a required space for a control while hidden will allocate space on the screen for the control. You need to find out, from developers, how they have implemented these things. I never used Coded-UI so I can't tell you what it's actually expecting.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. the only drawback is that involves changing the system. The system took many developers, many years to develop and will never stop growing. I am but 1 tester and I fear the horse has bolted in terms of making the system conform to any testability standards. Is there a way to test it as it is rather than raise a request for the dev team to make changes (which they won't do).

Comment: Have you had a look at [this article from MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3068c92-f1a3-47f2-81d0-7a7513b48443/cannot-perform-click-on-the-hidden-control-control-is-not-hidden-plainly-visible-to-user-and?forum=vstest)? It's just a workaround but it might help. Now to tackle the bigger fish, if your tests are not passing because of the way application was developed then you need to raise this with the dev team.

Comment: That article involves something that can't be found. The tester added a delay. I managed that issue with error handling and re-trys. Sometimes we need to add the "Container" of the control in our test to shown where it is.My issue is different, I have a display that shows 1 of 2 controls. BOTH controls, according to coded ui are always visible, exist, have a clickable point, state = OffScreen and no bounding rectangle to give me a clue. Why are they both the same at all times according to coded ui when I can see with own eyes that 1 is not on the screen and the other is?

Comment: Could you provide the xaml for these controls? Maybe we can figure this out easier with some samples.

Comment: XAMIMAX, Many thanks, you have forced me to explain the ins and outs and so finally I have been forced to reason it out and therefore find the answer. It was two-fold. Misleadingly, TryGetClickablePoint is always false, exists is always true, Top is always -1 and width is always -1. Hmm. The solution was to use a Container AND then check the State (as nothing else was behaving). So I had 2 problems, Many Thanks again, full answer below.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was two-fold. Firstly I had to find the element and this was not working properly with my recorded steps. The element was buried too deeply in the system under test which is WPF (XAML). Secondly I had to prove I had found the element and for this I can't use TryGetClickablePoint, Exists, Top or Width. None of them seemed to work properly at all for my element. I had to use State.

```
    public void Assert_MyElementShown()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WpfCustom uISurfaceCustom = this.UISysUnderTestClientShWindow.UIItemCustom1.UISurfaceCustom;
        WpfCustom uIYAxisLabelsCustom = new WpfCustom();
        #endregion

        //Find the Element using it's Container and SearchProperties
        uIYAxisLabelsCustom.Container = uISurfaceCustom;
        uIYAxisLabelsCustom.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Uia.AxisLabelControl";
        uIYAxisLabelsCustom.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "YAxisLabels";

        //Use the State to find if it's on screen or not
        var state = uIYAxisLabelsCustom.State;

        if (state == Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.ControlStates.Default)
        {
            //Element is visible, do stuff here!
        }
        else if (state == Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.ControlStates.Offscreen)
        {
            //The control may exist, it may have location on screen and may even 
            //appear to be clickable according to coded ui framework but is is NOT
            //shown on the screen. 
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach for your application..if control properties are showing true for viable than we can go for height and width.Means if control is not visible in UI and but still all properties are showing true than check control height and width must be in -ve number.Than we can keep a assertion like

If control.height<0
Not visible in UI

Comment: Thanks, that approach works sometimes but didn't work in my case. I had to use "Container" (to reliably find the element) AND "State" to determine it's state. It's height and Width were positive values whether I could see it or not. WPF applications can be funny depending on how they're developed...